# What are the main benefits of Azure Digital Twin?

Tags: azure-digital-twins

I was going through Azure new offering Digital Twin and trying to understand what makes it different and unique so that organization will use it and will not invest in developing theirs own DT systems.

I also posted the question on https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Internet-of-Things-Show/Getting-started-with-Azure-Digital-Twins?term=%22Azure%20Digital%20Twins%22&lang-en=true and got the response for https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-iot/at-the-end-of-the-day-what-is-digital-twins-about/m-p/759502#.XS9eIPFF0Pc.link

All links explains the functional details but nowhere it is mentioned what are the core components for building ADT, internal details and how much effort goes to build one w.r.t to using Azure offering. obviously, it is PaaS offering so it will always beneficial to use one then creating one but what are components will need to create one.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Digital Twins provides its own Swagger and API and a Spatial Graph.
That's the benefits of Azure Digital Twins.

In my company we made a POC of ADT, and now we are looking to implement another solution to replace it because in Preview Version it has some limits. (100 message / seconds is not enough for us).
But to replace it we will need to completly redesign the Spatial Graph and to redefine every single item that Azure Digital Twins allows you to use. (Devices / Sensors / Spaces)
It's really complicated to do that.

I think that the solution provided by MS is clearly great to treat with IoT objects, smartbuilding because of that SpatialGraph and API.